# Merge sort implementation in c++ using vectors

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, mergesort

I'm trying to implement merge sort using vectors in C++, this is the following code I'm executing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void merge(vector<int> &a, int l, int m, int r) {
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 = r - m;
    
    int L[n1], R[n2];
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        L[i] = a[l + i];
    }
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
        L[j] = a[m + 1 + j];
    }
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = l;     //merged array
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
            a[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            a[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i < n1) {
        a[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < n2) {
        a[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

void mergeSort(vector<int> &a, int l, int r) {
    if (l < r) {
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;
        mergeSort(a, l, m);
        mergeSort(a, m + 1, r);
        merge(a, l, m, r);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    vector<int> a(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    mergeSort(a, 0, a.size() - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        cout << a[i];
    }
}
```

When I execute this and enter any values, I get garbage values returned in the array, `a[i] = 7405024`, Is the code giving me error due to the fact that I can't change values of the  vector in-place or is there something else.

Comment: use your debugger to go through your program line by line and inspect the contents of your variables at each step. Find exactly where and when the contents of your variables start to differ from what you expect.

Comment: The main issue I think I'm facing is passing values not by reference which causes the vector to not  update

Comment: Whichever C++ textbook taught you to write "`int L[n1],R[n2];`", please throw it away and get a better C++ textbook. This is not standard C++. Besides that, yes, this is what a debugger is for. Use your debugger to walk through your program, one line at a time, inspect the values of all variables, and observe them as they change. That's the only way you can prove your hypothesis as to what your "main issue" is.

Comment: a.size() returns how many contents there are in vector. Probably you wanted to use a.capacity(); once i had same type of error for using "vector<int> a(n);" try without initializing with a capacity like "vector<int> a;" and loop  be "for(i;i<n;i++)"

Comment: No, @Yasir, at least the part that uses `size()` is correct. Why exactly do you believe that `capacity()` should be used here?

Comment: presumably `L[j]=a[m+1+j];` should be `R[j]=a[m+1+j];`

Comment: @sam because vector.size() returns how many contents there are I suppose and as he defined a capacity for vector he can check for until he reached the predefined capacity that will be equal to 'int n' in this context

Comment: @Yasir `std::vector<int> myVector(5);` declares a vector with 5 elements (aka `size()==5`) and unspecified capacity. The elements are already there, OP is just changing them. Using `capacity()` only makes sense if you you will `push_back` a number of them and you don't want to or cannot create default objects.

Comment: @yasir vector capacity has absolutely nothing to do with anything, whatsoever, here. And as far as sorting a vector, "how many contents there are" is exactly what's needed, instead of "how much it could have before reallocation occurs". That just does not make any sense.

Comment: @shawnindamnen: can you please accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the `merge` function

```
for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
{
    R[j]=a[m+1+j]; // not L[j]
}
```

As you are implementing using vectors, suggest to change `L` and `R` to vectors as well. VLAs are not supported by C++ by default. Some compilers may accept, but should avoid using altogether.

```
std::vector<int> L(n1);
std::vector<int> R(n2);
```

Answer (score 1):

One obvious change that I can see is

```
IN merge() function

for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
{
    R[j]=a[m+1+j];
}
```

as those values have to be stored in `RIGHT` vector.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your initialisation of `R`. Rather than writing loops to copy into `L` and `R`, you can just initialise them directly.

```
std::vector<int> L(a.begin() + l, a.begin() + m + 1);
std::vector<int> R(a.begin() + m + 1, a.begin() + r + 1);
```

Note that it's easier to just use iterators everywhere.

```
using iter = std::vector<int>::iterator;

void merge(iter l, iter m, iter r) {
    std::vector<int> L(l, m);
    std::vector<int> R(m, r);
    
    iter i = L.begin();
    iter j = R.begin();
    while (i != L.end() && j != R.end()) {
        if (*i < *j) {
            *l = *i;
            i++;
        } else {
            *l = *j;
            j++;
        }
        l++;
    }

    std::copy(i, L.end(), l);
}

void mergeSort(iter l, iter r) {
    std::size_t d = std::distance(l, r);
    if (d > 1) {
        iter m = l + (d / 2);
        mergeSort(l, m);
        mergeSort(m, r);
        merge(l, m, r);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::size_t n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> a(n);
    for (int & i : a) {
        std::cin >> i;
    }
    mergeSort(a.begin(), a.end());
    for (int i : a) {
        std::cout << i;
    }
}
```

Note that you can advance `l` until you find an element ordered after `*m` before initialising `L`, which saves some copying.

Answer (score 0):

**You can implement Merge Sort using the below code:**

```
vector<int> merge(vector<int> l,vector<int> r)
        {
    
       vector<int> res;
            
            int i=0;
            int j=0;
            while(i!=l.size() && j!=r.size())
            {
                if(l[i]<=r[j])
                {
                    re.push_back(l[i++]);
                }
                else
                {
                    re.push_back(r[j++]);
                }
            }
            
            while(i!=l.size())
                re.push_back(l[i++]);
            
            while(j!=r.size())
                re.push_back(r[j++]);
            
            return res;
        }
        
        
        vector<int> merge_d(vector<int>&A, int s,int e)
        {
            if(s-e==0)
            {
                vector<int> t;
                t.push_back(A[s]);
                return t;
            }
        
            int m=(s+e)/2;
            
            vector<int> l;
            vector<int> r;
            l=merge_d(A,s,m);
            r=merge_d(A,m+1,e);
            
            return merge(l,r);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your code is you do not initialize `R` at all. There is a simple typo in the initialization loop, probably a cut and paste error: `L[j] = a[m + 1 + j];` should be

```
R[j] = a[m + 1 + j];
```

Note also that it is idiomatic in C++ to specify a slice with the index of the first element included and the index of the last element excluded. This convention, used in C, Python and many other languages, allows for simpler and more generic code you can specify an empty slice with `l == h`. It is also less error prone as no `+1`/`-1` adjustments are necessary and unsigned index types such as `size_t` can be used safely.

Finally, `int L[n1], R[n2];` is a C99 declaration that is an extension to C++. Even in environments where VLAs are supported, allocating them with automatic storage will cause a **stack overflow** for sufficiently large sets. You should use `vector` for these temporary arrays.

These vectors can be initialized directly from a vector slice, which avoids the error-prone copying loops:

```
vector<int> L(a.begin() + l, a.begin() + m);
vector<int> R(a.begin() + m, a.begin() + r);
```

Here is a modified version:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void merge(vector<int> &a, size_t l, size_t m, size_t r) {
    vector<int> L(a.begin() + l, a.begin() + m);
    vector<int> R(a.begin() + m, a.begin() + r);

    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;
    size_t k = l;     // index into the merged vector slice
    size_t n1 = m - l;
    size_t n2 = r - m;

    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
            a[k++] = L[i++];
        } else {
            a[k++] = R[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < n1) {
        a[k++] = L[i++];
    }
    // the last loop in redundant as the remaining elements from R are already at
    // the end of a
}

void mergeSort(vector<int> &a, size_t l, size_t r) {
    if (r - l >= 2) {
        size_t m = l + (r - l) / 2;
        mergeSort(a, l, m);
        mergeSort(a, m, r);
        merge(a, l, m, r);
    }
}

int main() {
    size_t n;
    std::cin >> n;
    vector<int> a(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    mergeSort(a, 0, a.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        cout << a[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```